# Ionic Toggle With Dropdown not working

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, ionic-framework, toggle

I am working on ionic and stucked on one point that I want ionic toggle button with Dropdown in a row.Means Toggle name then dropdown then button . I have created a PEN for this `**http://codepen.io/anujsphinx/pen/aBBMVg**` . Need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointer events are turned off with `CSS` in ionic toggle. You have to override the css. I added class to toggle and used css to do that.

HTML:

```
 <ion-toggle ng-repeat="item in settingsList"
        ng-model="item.checked" ng-checked="item.checked" class="offPointer">
      {{ item.text }}
      <select>     
          <option>Option 1</option>
          <option selected>Option 2</option>
         <option>Option 3</option>
       </select>
    </ion-toggle>
```

CSS:

```
.offPointer{
  pointer-events: all !important;
}
```

You can find the full code here. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBLGeK?editors=1100

Let me know if this doesn't help you.